# Serial port communication from C# application deployment issue

Tags: c#, serial-port

I have an application in which operators are authenticated from their RFID for every operation, The RFID scanner is connected to a serial port(COM1).

Issue I am facing here is ,first time I am trying to read the data from Serial port it is working as expected and second time on wards it gives me a junk value and even I try to make setup for the same but then it works totally unexpected. Here is my code, please suggest me a solution.

**Form load event Code**

---

```
   _serialPort = new SerialPort("COM1");

        _serialPort.BaudRate = 57600;
        _serialPort.DataBits = 8;
        _serialPort.Parity = Parity.Even;
        _serialPort.StopBits = StopBits.Two;
        _serialPort.Handshake = Handshake.None;
        _serialPort.Encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("Windows-1252");

        _serialPort.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(port_DataReceived);
        _serialPort.Open();
```

**port_DataReceived event**

```
void port_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {

            char[] SerialPortHexChar = new char[48];
            _serialPort.Read(SerialPortHexChar, 0, 48);

            ValidateCard(SerialPortHexChar);//Here there is no reference of _serialPort object.
        }
        catch { }
    }
```

**Form unload**

```
private void Window_Unloaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
           if(_serialPort.IsOpen)
                _serialPort.Close();
           _serialPort.Dispose();
        }
        catch { }

    }
```

***Thanks in advance...***

Comment: Are you closing & disposing your serial port after use? If not, you may get junk as the two connections compete.

Comment: When are you creating _serialPort. Suggest you create and dispose around each request, get clever later if required.

Comment: Yes, I am closing the _serialPort object on form unload.Thanks Iain Ballard &  Tony Hopkinson

Comment: There's a bug in your DataReceived event handler.  Nobody can see it.

Comment: Agree with Hans, fix the access to port_DataRec'd() and would need to see your logic inside the function to see if you are clearing all the bytes off the port each read.